# Spring SpEL condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have added few event listeners like:

```
@EventListener(condition = "#message.state == 'sync'")
@EventListener(condition = "#message.state == 'update'")
```

It works.
I need *default* one (to listen to all other cases for example `message.state IS NOT IN ['sync', 'update']`).

Can I have suggestion, how it can be done in good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"#message.state != 'sync' && #message.state != 'update'"`

??

Comment: Or you can call methods in other beans.. `@EventListener(condition = "@fooBean.shouldHandle(event)")`